# Sublime Text 3 Sidebar folders do not open at start (OSX)

Tags: macos, directory, sublimetext3, sidebar

On Ubuntu Sublime Text 3 has the option to "Open Folder..." to keep a folderstructure in the sidebar. All Subfolders are shown whenever I open ST3. BUT on Mac this option doesn't exist. I can say "Open File..." and select that folder which keeps it inside the sidebar but only for the current session. After I restart the Program my Sidebar with all its folders from the last time is gone. 
Is there some way to fix it? Is it a bug or an non-existent feature on Mac?

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to [Sublime Text - Preferences - Settings User](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ps5Mo.png)
2. Then add this code:
   {
   "hot_exit": true,
   }
3. Hit CMD+Q (Quit the app)

Start after few seconds. That worked for me